# ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql

## Problem

I encountered this error during a Mysql DB dump and restore. None of the solutions posted anywhere solved my problem, so I thought I post my own answer I found on my own for posterity.

- **Source Env:**
  CentOS 4 i386 ext3, Mysql 5.5 dump, Most tables engines are MySIAM, with a few InnoDBs.
- **Destination Env:**
  CentOS 6 x66_64 XFS, Mysql 5.6

Source DB is 25GB on disk, and a gzipped dump is 4.5GB.

### Dump

Dump command from source -> destination was run like so:

```
mysqldump $DB_NAME | gzip -c | sudo ssh $USER@$IP_ADDRESS 'cat > /$PATH/$DB_NAME-`date +%d-%b-%Y`.gz'
```

This makes the dump, gzips on the fly, and writes it over SSH to the source. You don't have to do it this way, but it is convenient.

### Import

On the new source DB I ran the import like so:

```
gunzip < /$PATH/$DB_NAME.gz | mysql -u root $DB_NAME
```

Note that you have to issue `CREATE DATABASE DB_NAME` SQL to make the new empty detination DB before starting the import.

Everytime I tried this I got this type of error:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line MySQL server has gone away
```

### Source DB conf

My source DB is a virt server using VMWare so I can resize the RAM/CPU as needed. For this project I temporarily scaled up to 8CPU/16GB of RAM, and then scaled back down after the import. This is a luxury I had, that you may not.

With so much RAM I was able to tune the heck out of the /etc/my.cnf file. Everyone else had suggested increasing

```
max-allowed-packet
bulk_insert_buffer_size
```

To double or triple default values. This didn't fix it for me. Then I tried increasing timeouts after reading more online.

```
interactive_timeout
wait_timeout
net_read_timeout
net_write_timeout
connect_timeout
```

I did this and it still didn't work. So then I went crazy and set everything unreasonably high. Here is what I ended up with:

```
key_buffer_size=512M
table_cache=2G
sort_buffer_size=512M
max-allowed-packet=2G
bulk_insert_buffer_size=2G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
net_buffer_length=1000000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
innodb_file_per_table
interactive_timeout=600
wait_timeout=600
net_read_timeout=300
net_write_timeout=300
connect_timeout=300
```

Still no luck. I felt deflated. Then I noticed that the import kept failing at the same spot. So I reviewed the SQL. I noticed nothing strange. Nothing in the log files either.

## Solution

There's something about the DB structure that's causing the import to fail. I suspect it's size related, but who knows.

To fix it I started splitting the dumps up into smaller chunks. The source DB has about 75 tables. So I made 3 dumps with approx 25 each. You just have to pass the table names to the dump command. For ex:

```
mysqldump $DB_NAME $TABLE1> $TABLE2....$TABLE25 | gzip -c | sudo ssh $USER@$IP_ADDRESS 'cat > /$PATH/$DB_NAME-TABLES1-25`date +%d-%b-%Y`.gz'
```

Then I simply imported each chunk independently on the destination. Finally, no errors. Hopefully this is useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was to split the dump into chunks by tables. Then do multiple imports. See details in the original post.